# Request Media Type[application/json] Error! Request Body is not JSON format issue for Extjs Ajax request

Tags: json, ajax, extjs

I am using Extjs 5.1.3. I have post request with params as-

```
{"root":{"countryId":"458","ruleId":"3386","ruleName":"Test1 \\","ruleType":"CELL_STORE","opType":"DETAILS"}}
```

I am creating ajax request as-

```
  Ext.Ajax.request({
                       method: 'POST',
                       url: appurl.fetchRuleDetails,
                       params: win.jsonData,
                       callback: function(option, success, response){
                           })
                   })
```

From server side, response is coming as-

```
{
  "rules":[
    {
      "countryId":"458",
      "ruleId":"3386",
      "ruleName":"Test1 \\",
      "ruleType":"CELL_STORE",
      "ruleParts":[
        {
          "seq":"1",
          "attrId":"6",
          "attrName":"Store Type",
          "op":"=",
          "val":"dsafdaf",
          "charType":"GLOBAL_CHAR"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Status":{
    "StatusFlag":true,
    "StatusCode":"SUCCESS",
    "StatusMessage":"SUCCESS"
  }
}
```

But in Ajax request's callback function, we are receiving response.responseText as-
Request Media Type[application/json] Error! Request Body is not JSON format.

My guess is like issue is because of rulename value as "Test1 \".
So can someone please help me whats missing.

Comment: This isn't related to Ext, your server is responding that it can't read the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is not an ExtJS error message. If you receive an ExtJS error related to invalid JSON, it will look like this:

> Uncaught Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: TestTest

My best guess is that the error message comes from the server, because it expects you to send your request as JSON. Right now you are sending it as FormData. To send the request as JSON, you have to put your object in the `jsonData` config and leave the `params` config undefined:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: appurl.fetchRuleDetails,
    jsonData: win.jsonData,
    callback: function(option, success, response){
    })
})
```

For future questions regarding server-client communication, please keep in mind that you should first check in your browser network tab what you send to the server and what the response from the server really is.

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. Actually, i checked request and response using chrome's rest client add-on also...Server is sending response correctly as required properly in json format.But in Ajax request's callback function, we are receiving response.responseText as- Request Media Type[application/json] Error! Request Body is not JSON format. It is something weird. If in request params i am replacing, ruleName from "Test1 \" to "Test1", i am able to get corresponding response correctly in callback. So according to me, issue is because of special character used. I am not sure why its happening.